# Laravel 5.3 - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and I am enjoying it. While working on a social media project I got this error: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\histoirevraie\resources\views\user\profile.blade.php)`

I have checked some questions on this site but I have not found a question that solves my problem.

this is what my `profile.blade.php` is made of:

```
<ul class="profile-rows">
    <li>
        <span class="the-label">Last visit: </span>
        <span class="the-value mark green">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user->lastVisit)->diffForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::now())}}</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="the-label">Member since: </span>
        <span class="the-value mark light-gray">{{ $user->created_at->format('F Y') }}</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="the-label">Profile views: </span>
        <span class="the-value mark light-gray">5146</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="the-label">Living In: </span>
        <span class="the-value">{{ $user->town }}</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="the-label">Website: </span>
        <span class="the-value"><a href="{{ url($user->website) }}">{{ $user->website }}</a></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

All the information about the user are given by a controller:

```
public function index($username){
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        return view('user.profile', compact('user'));
    }
```

Kindly help me solve this problem!

Comment: Maybe some of the variables between `{{ }}` is a object? Try to dump all of them in the controller.

Comment: Is `$user->website` blank possibly? The `url()` helper method will give you an _instance_ of `UrlGenerator` if you don't give it a string.

Comment: @jszobody you are right. Post your answser please

Comment: in my case i have given object inside `{{ }}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think your `$user->website` is empty/blank.

If you look at the [`url()` helper method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L808-L810), Laravel will return an *instance* of `UrlGenerator` if `$path` is null.

So in your case if `$user->website` is empty, you'd get `UrlGenerator` back and thus your error about `htmlspecialchars` getting an object.

One simple solution would be to wrap your html chunk with a check:

```
@if($user->website)
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i used a function inside blade file like `$brand->products()` and it was returning array, thats why i was seeing the message.

when i changed my code and returning string, the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this because in my view I was using `$errors->get('username')`  to show errors but `get()` returns an array. Switching to `$errors->first('username')` fixed this.