# Convert mysql json field to object in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have this table in Mysql, details column is a json type.
[image: Sample table capture]

This is the OrderDetails model

```
class OrderDetail extends Model
{   
    protected $casts = [
        'details' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

This is the controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $result = OrderDetail::where('details->options->size', 'L')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();

        return view('home', compact(['result']));
     }
}
```

And the home view

```
@if($result->count())
    @foreach($result as $item)
        <li>{{ $item->details }}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Im getting this error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /***/resources/views/home.blade.php)

But if i remove the **protected $casts[]** from the model it shows me the JSON, how can i convert the details field in to an object having the the **id** and **order_id** fields in the same query?

**Edit**

Now i have get a JSON to object conversion inserting a `foreach` with a `json_decode` and removing the `protected $casts[]` from the model, is there a better way to this?

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $result = OrderDetail::where('details->options->size', 'L')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();

        foreach($result as $key => $item){
               $result[$key]->details = json_decode($item->details);
        }

        return view('home', compact('result'));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Laravel 5.3 - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40045920/6521116)

Comment: @KrisRoofe I check this before, but is there any way to get the json field as an object to avoid this in blade **{{ $item->details['options']['size'] }}** ?

Comment: cast it as object.

Answer (score 2):

Remove square brackets from `compact` function

```
return view('home', compact('result'));
```

Comment: I try this before and the **htmlspecialchars() ** error persist.