# Getting error while passing decoded json data from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

when I use `dd($arr)` in controller the decoded json data gets printed correctly. How can I pass this decoded json data into my view?

Controller Code

```
public function test()
{
    // $sld = $request['sld'];
    // $tld = $request['tld'];
    $response = Curl::to('https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=decksys&tld=info&responsetype=xml&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw')
        ->get();

   //check if we are getting a response

 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $json   = json_encode($xml);

 $arr = json_decode($json, true);
 dd($arr);
 return view('clientlayout.main.test', compact('arr'));

}
```

Blade File:

```
`{{ $arr }}`
```

My Route file is given below:

```
 Route::get('/test','EnomController@test');
```

How to solve this error?

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: what is a output shown in dd($arr)

Comment: This is the output of dd($arr)

array:19 [▼
  "Command" => "CHECK"
  "APIType" => "API.NET"
  "Language" => "eng"
  "ErrCount" => "1"
  "errors" => array:1 [▶]
  "ResponseCount" => "1"
  "responses" => array:1 [▶]
  "MinPeriod" => "1"
  "MaxPeriod" => "10"
  "Server" => "sjl0vwapi16"
  "Site" => "eNom"
  "IsLockable" => "True"
  "IsRealTimeTLD" => "True"
  "TimeDifference" => "+7.00"
  "ExecTime" => "0.036"
  "Done" => "true"
  "TrackingKey" => "999b66f5-5485-4dfa-bb9e-8424d4d0e9ae"
  "RequestDateTime" => "5/4/2018 11:56:38 PM"
  "debug" => []
]

Comment: ok I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('clientlayout.main.test', compact('arr'))->with('arr', $arr);
```

and your view: `{{ $data['obj'] }}` will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this error is already available on stack, you are accessing those objects which are empty or blank here is a link of solution:
[htmlspecialchars expects parameter 1 to be string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045920/laravel-5-3-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string)

ok in controller use curl like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
            "https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=decksys&tld=info&responsetype=json&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
$arr  = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

then return data to view, use foreach loop in view like:

```
@foreach($arr as $item)
    {{$item['Command']}}
    {{$item['APIType']}}
@endforeach
```

and want to check before print use isset:

```
@if(isset($item['Command']))
    {{$item['Command']}}
@endif
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is ok. But the issue is, the data from the above json is not getting displayed / printed in my view file. When I use  {{$item['Command']}} I'm getting illegal string offset Command.

Comment: API is returning xml and after conversion to json it is given json validation error. I recommended to use responseType=json in API like:[https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=decksys&tld=info&responsetype=json&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw]