# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

This is Controller. I named it CartController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use App\Product;

class CartController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $cartItems=Cart::content();
    return view('cart.index', compact('cartItems'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $product=Product::find($id);

    Cart::add($id,$product->name,'1',$product->price);
}
```

This is my welcome.blade.php. This is the page where I display all my Items.

```
<div class="row">
@forelse($books->chunk(4) as $chunk)
  @foreach($chunk as $book)
    <div class="column-prod">
<a href="{{url('view')}}">
<div class="card-prod">
<center><img src="{{url('images',$book->image)}}"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></center> </a>
  <div class="container-prod">
    <h2></h2>
    <p class="title">{{$book->name}}</p>
    <p class="price">₱ {{$book->price}}</p>

    <p><a href="{{ route('cart.edit',$book->id)}}" class="button"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>Add to Cart</button></a></p>
    <p><button class="button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>  Add to Wishlist</button></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endforeach 
@empty
<h3> No Books </h3>
@endforelse 


 </div> <!--Div all end-->
```

This is the codes of my Cart Page. When the user click add to cart in the welcome page, his/her chosen items will be place in this page.

```
  <h3> Cart Items </h3>

  <!--TABLE NAMESSS-->
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th scope="col">Image</th>
                               <th scope="col">Name</th>
                               <th scope="col">Price</th>
                               <th scope="col">Quantity</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>


            <tbody> 
                @foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)
                <li>{{$cartItem->name}}</li>
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{url('images',$cartItem->image)}}</td>
                        <td>{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
                        <td>{{$cartItem->qty}}</td>

                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is my route.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome')->with(['books' => \App\Product::all()]);
});

Route::get('/cart','ShopController@cart');

Route::get('/signin','ShopController@signin');



Route::resource('/cart','CartController');

Route::get('/wishlist','ShopController@wish');



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::get('/',function(){
            return view('admin.index');
        })->name('admin.index');


        Route::resource('product','ProductsController');
        Route::resource('category','CategoriesController');
});

Route::get('/categ', function(){
return view ('admin.category.categ_index');

});
```

I'm confused I don't know how to fix my error. This is the complete error that the system return.

"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)"

I hope you can help me in solving this. Your answers are very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045920/laravel-5-3-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string)

Comment: hi! can you edit my code and how to do it? I'm confused in this type of error. thanks

Comment: You can start by checking the values of `$book->image` and anything inside `{{ }}` if they're a string. i.e `var_dump($book->image); die;`

Comment: Where did you use "htmlspecialchars()" this function, can you please share the line of codes where it is?

Comment: @SachinVairagi hi! 
Here it is, maybe...

    public function edit($id)
      {
        $product=Product::find($id);

        Cart::add($id,$product->name,1,$product->price);
     }


the number 1 must be the number of quantity that the user wants to purchase.

Comment: Please share line of codes throwing an error or as suggested by @hungrykoala, you can try dd($book); after foreach, like this - @foreach($chunk as $book) dd($book); and share the output.

Comment: @SachinVairagi 

C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php
 
        die(1);
    }
}
 
if (! function_exists('e')) {
    
  
 
 
    function e($value, $doubleEncode = false)
    {
        if ($value instanceof Htmlable) {
            return $value->toHtml();
        }
 
        return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
    }
}

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Which of those two methods/views show the error?